# getting the names of data frames from list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names

I have a list which contains 36 data frames. I want to create a list containing all the names of those data frames :

```
   dput(myfiles[1:2])
list(structure(list(X.Treatment.1.Treatment.10.Treatment.2.Treatment.3.Treatment.4.Treatment.5.Treatment.6.Treatment.7.Treatment.8.Treatment.9 = c("Treatment.1,1,0.779269898976048,0.987582177817029,0.999865208543176,0.999637376053903,0.969316946773183,0.992798203986959,0.424960684181985,0.804869101320034,0.934784678841289", 
"Treatment.10,0.779269898976048,1,0.671138248567996,0.789454098761072,0.762111859396959,0.909408486972833,0.848734212632234,-0.236126723371631,0.255300504533133,0.505840502482398", 
"Treatment.2,0.987582177817029,0.671138248567996,1,0.984869671366683,0.991454531822078,0.918661911614817,0.961649044703906,0.561895346303209,0.888107698459535,0.978982111839266", 
"Treatment.3,0.999865208543176,0.789454098761072,0.984869671366683,1,0.99906051831384,0.973222174821046,0.994631289318653,0.410041249133801,0.795017057233326,0.9288266084351", 
"Treatment.4,0.999637376053903,0.762111859396959,0.991454531822078,0.99906051831384,1,0.962346166096083,0.989212254209048,0.449182113577399,0.820557713571369,0.944010924367408", 
"Treatment.5,0.969316946773183,0.909408486972833,0.918661911614817,0.973222174821046,0.962346166096083,1,0.991784351747349,0.189407610662142,0.634294194129571,0.81878574572229", 
"Treatment.6,0.992798203986959,0.848734212632234,0.961649044703906,0.994631289318653,0.989212254209048,0.991784351747349,1,0.31345701514879,0.72797778020465,0.885498274066011", 
"Treatment.7,0.424960684181985,-0.236126723371631,0.561895346303209,0.410041249133801,0.449182113577399,0.189407610662142,0.31345701514879,1,0.879237827530393,0.718791431723663", 
"Treatment.8,0.804869101320034,0.255300504533133,0.888107698459535,0.795017057233326,0.820557713571369,0.634294194129571,0.72797778020465,0.879237827530393,1,0.963182415401058", 
"Treatment.9,0.934784678841289,0.505840502482398,0.978982111839266,0.9288266084351,0.944010924367408,0.81878574572229,0.885498274066011,0.718791431723663,0.963182415401058,1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)), structure(list(
    X.Treatment.1.Treatment.10.Treatment.2.Treatment.3.Treatment.4.Treatment.5.Treatment.6.Treatment.7.Treatment.8.Treatment.9 = c("Treatment.1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
    "Treatment.10,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA", "Treatment.2,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
    "Treatment.3,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA", "Treatment.4,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA", 
    "Treatment.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA", "Treatment.6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA", 
    "Treatment.7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA", "Treatment.8,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA", 
    "Treatment.9,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)))
```

I want a list containing all the names of the data frames. The problem is that when I write:

```
names(list_median)[i]
```

It just returns NULL. Each data frame in the list is a correlation matrix that looks like this.

Comment: What does `names(list_median)`, without the subsetting part return?

Comment: it returns NULL @Rui Barradas

Comment: If the df's are not very big, can you post the output of `dput(list_median[1:2])`? (Just the first 2 data.frames).

Comment: would it help to add pic to the Q? @ 
Rui Barradas

Comment: > dput(list_median[1:2])
list(structure(c(1, 0.779269898976048, 0.987582177817029, 0.999865208543176, 
0.999637376053903, 0.969316946773183, 0.992798203986959, 0.424960684181985, 
0.804869101320034, 0.934784678841289, 0.779269898976048, 1, 0.671138248567996, 
0.789454098761072, 0.762111859396959, 0.909408486972833, 0.848734212632234, 
-0.236126723371631, 0.255300504533133, 0.505840502482398, 0.987582177817029, 
0.671138248567996, 1, 0.984869671366683, 0.991454531822078, 0.918661911614817,

Comment: No, not as a comment, edit **the question** with the output of `dput`, please. And a picture is usually not a good way of posting data or code.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas
edited the Q

Comment: The list doesn't contain data.frames, it contains numeric matrices 10x10. And the matrices have the`dimnames` attribute set but the matrices themselves do not have names. You can access them with `list_median[[1]]`,  `list_median[[2]]`, etc. Are you asking for the `dimnames`?

Comment: what i did wrote :write.csv(df,"df) so now i have 36 csv files . then i read them together to a list:temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim) and it says that i have 36 data frames . so is there any way to have list with thier names?@
Rui Barradas

Comment: No, it wouldn't. See if my answer below is what you want.

Comment: what i did wrote :write.csv(df,"df) so now i have 36 csv files . then i read them together to a list:temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv") myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim) and it says that i have 36 data frames . so is there any way to have list with thier names?@ Rui Barradas

Comment: In that case, probably yes. What does `names(myfiles)` return now?

Comment: returns NULL @ 
Rui Barradas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240480/discussion-between-rui-barradas-and-eliza-r).

Comment: I guess. your list does not contain named dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding if this is it:

```
mat_names <- lapply(list_median, \(x) do.call(cbind, dimnames(x)))
mat_names <- lapply(mat_names, \(x) {colnames(x) <- c("Rows", "Cols"); x})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible explanation why you are running into issues. The code is commented:

```
# extract each dataframe to global environment with this code
for (i in seq(list_median))
  assign(paste0("df", i), list_median[[i]])

# you should see df1 and df2 etc.. in the Environment

# Now construct a list out of a few of df eg.df1 and df2 with a list of two dataframes:
my_list<- list(df1,df2)

# Now try to get the names
names(my_list)
# you will get NULL

# Now try this: name the dataframes like here and call the names:
my_list<- list(df1nownamed = df1, df2nownamed = df2)
names(my_list)

# and you will get:
[1] "df1nownamed" "df2nownamed"
```